# How to ignore 0(zero) values in SQL query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, c#-4.0, left-join

For example:

```
 food fee   admission fee 
 ------------------------
   100          0 
     0        100 
    50         50 
     0          0
```

I want query which ignores 0 (zero) values in both fees fields.so output should be

```
 100     0
   0   100
  50    50
```

Code

```
WITH cteReports AS
(
    SELECT               
        tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee, tblStudentFees.BankFee, 
        tblStudentFees.BookFee, tblStudentFees.ClassName, tblStudentFees.Date, 
        tblStudentFees.DivisionName, tblStudentFees.FoodFee, 
        tblStudentFees.OtherFee, tblStudentFees.OtherFee2, 
        tblStudentFees.StationaryFee, tblStudentFees.StudentFeesId, 
        tblStudentFees.StudentNo, tblStudentFees.Total, tblStudent.Name, 
        users.Username, tblState.StateName, tblStudent.StateId, 
        tblStudent.DistrictId, tblStudent.Name AS Expr1, 
        users.Username AS Expr2, tblStudent.CityName, 
        tblStudentFees.PaymentType, tblStudentFees.AccountNo,
        tblStudent.Study
    FROM 
        tblStudentFees AS tblStudentFees 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblStudent AS tblStudent ON tblStudent.StudentNo = tblStudentFees.StudentNo 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblState AS tblState ON tblState.StateId = tblStudent.StateId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblUser AS users ON tblStudentFees.InsertBy = users.UserId
    WHERE 
        tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee != 0.00 
        AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee = 0.00 
         OR tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee = 0.00 
        AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee != 0.00 
         OR tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee!= 0.00 
        AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee != 0.00
)
SELECT
    AdmissionFee, FoodFee, BankFee, BookFee, ClassName,
    Date, DivisionName, OtherFee, OtherFee2, 
    StationaryFee, StudentFeesId, StudentNo, Total,
    Name, Username, StateName, StateId, DistrictId,
    Expr1, Expr2, CityName, PaymentType, AccountNo 
FROM 
    cteReports 
WHERE
    CityName LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' 
    AND Date >= @dtfrom 
    AND Date <= @dtTo 
    AND Study = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore ? just replace them by NULL or ' ' or don't display them at all ?

Comment: no both 0 0 should not be displayed

Comment: You can filter the sum of rows which are zero

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets when using OR.

for example

```
(tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee != 0.00 
AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee = 0.00) 
 OR (tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee = 0.00 
AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee != 0.00) 
 OR (tblStudentFees.AdmissionFee!= 0.00 
AND tblStudentFees.FoodFee != 0.00)
```

A simpler way to write this would be:

```
WHERE NOT (FoodFee = 0 AND AdmissionFee = 0)
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect the parenthesis to be required due to logical operator precedence.

Comment: @DanGuzman You're absolutely right, I had to try it myself.

I assumed it was an error in order of operation, but actually op's logic worked perfectly in practice. Now I'm confused as to how my result solved anything, other than readability.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping, me too but the less verbose technique in your answer works too.